# Position is ambiguous for image view

Tags: ios, xcode, image, imageview, position

I'm just following the tutorial from Apple, and I get an error when I set the ratio 1:1 to the image view:

[image]

I think it's because the tutorial is for xCode 7, so how to fix it ?

Answer (score 7):

From the snapshot you provided, you were not using **Stack View**, so you probably were following the older tutorial.

I also had this problem when I was following apple's tutorial, and it turned out that I placed the image view out of my **Stack View**, which gives me the error you mentioned; and more importantly, when I tested the app and chose an image, the image was displayed at its original size.

So the solution for me is simple: placing image view into the **Stack View**, as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to set all the constraint for the ui elements. Aspect ratio isn't enough, you should set the x and y position too for that image. *(e.g.: leading space to View and top space to Button)*

If you want to use auto layout, you should allways set all the constraints for all the elements.

**EDIT - for better understanding**

Just setting the aspect ratio for a view isn't enough. You should give other position and size data too. 
In this example, the `Leading Space to: Superview` set the X coordinate. The `Top Space to Top Layout Guide` set the Y coordinate. After that we set aspect ratio, and width, or height data for the view. Like the image below.

For better understanding I recommended you to check Stanford iOS developer lessons in iTunesU. Thats will help you understand auto layout.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where can I set the x and y position ?

Comment: Just set the constraint for it. Ctrl + drag to other elements. 
Eg.: if you set the leading space to the base View, then x is ready, after that set the top space constraint to the Button, -> y is ready. Ofc. you need to set this for the other UI elements too.

Comment: I try to do but I don't understan when I do aspect ratio they re the error and you say: ctrl + drag imageview to an another object but it offers many choices